# Von Neumann's minimax theorem and Carathéodory's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, convex-analysis, game-theory

In [J.F. Mertens(1986)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01769388)(Paywall), there's a neat proof of a version of Von Neumann's minimax theorem. But I can't understand how Carathéodory's theorem is invoked.

Suppose, in a two-person zero sum game, player I's strategy space is a compact set $S$, while player II' strategy space is a finite set $T = \{t_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$. $f : S \times T \to \Bbb R \cup \{-\infty, + \infty\}$ is player I's payoff function, which is uppersemicontinuous and bounded either from above or below. To show the mixed extension of this game has a value:

[image]

I guess [Carathéodory's theorem](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/%7Ethanh/paper/alg.pdf) here is referred to:

> For $S ⊂ \Bbb R^d$, if $x ∈ \operatorname{conv}(S)$ then $x ∈ \operatorname{conv}(R)$ for some
> $R ⊂ S$,$|R| ≤ d + 1$.

I can't see how this imply that we only need to consider player I's mixed strategies with a finite support no more than $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be a strategy for the first player (that is, $\sigma$ is a probability distribution on $S$). Define vector $u(s) = (f(s,t_1),\dots,f(s,t_n))$ for every $s\in S$ and vector $v(\sigma) = (v_1(\sigma), \dots, v_n(\sigma))$ by
$v_i(\sigma) = \int_S f(s,t_i) d\sigma(s)$. We have,
$$v(\sigma) = \int_S u(s) d\sigma(s).$$
Suppose that player II uses strategy $\tau$. Then the value of the game (when I uses $\sigma$ and II uses $\tau$) equals
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\int_S f(s,t_i) d\sigma(s) \cdot \tau(t_i)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(\sigma) \tau(t_i).$$
Observe that if $v(\sigma_1) = v(\sigma_2)$ for two strategies $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ then for every strategy $\tau$ of II, the the game has the same value when I uses strategy $\sigma_1$ and when I uses strategy $\sigma_2$. That is, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are *equivalent*.

We show that for every strategy $\sigma$, there is an *equivalent* strategy $\sigma'$ with support of size at most $n+1$. Since
$$v(\sigma) = \int_S u(s) d\sigma(s) = \mathbb{E}_{s\sim \sigma}[u(s)],$$
vector $v(\sigma)$ lies in the convex hull of vectors $\{u(s):s\in S\}$ (see [Mathematical expectation is inside convex hull of support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284153/mathematical-expectation-is-inside-convex-hull-of-support) for an explanation why this is the case). By Carathéodory's theorem, we have that $v(\sigma)$ is a convex combination of at most $n+1$ vectors $u(s_1),\dots, u(s_{n+1})$ for some $s_1,\dots,s_{n+1}\in S$. That is, there is a distribution $\sigma'$ on $s_1,\dots, s_{n+1}$ equivalent to $\sigma$. In other words, 
$$v(\sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \sigma'(s_i) u(s_i).$$

Comment: Dear sir, thank you for your answer. I don't follow why $v(\sigma) = \int_{S} u(s) d\sigma(s)$ implies that $v(\sigma)$ is a convex combination of $u(s)$. Say, $S$ is infinite and can be a indexed by the unit interval $[0,1]$, and $\sigma'$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. I can't see why in this case $v(\sigma') = \int_{[0,1]} u(s) d\sigma'(s)$ can be reprsented as a convex combination of $u(s)$, that is, there is a finite $N$ such that $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq N}\alpha_i u(s_i)= v(\sigma')$ and $\sum_{1 \leq i \leq N}\alpha_i = 1$.

Comment: Another question is that there's a difference between your upperbound of size of support of equivalent strategy and Mertens'. Yours is $n+1$, but his is $n$.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace, 

1. By the definition of the convex hull, $v(S) = \int_S u(S)d\sigma(s)\in \mathrm{conv}(S)$. Note that $v(S)$ lies in $n$ dimensional space. By Minkwoski's theorem, $v(S) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_i s_i$ for some $s_1,\dots, s_{n+1}$. Let me know if you have further questions.

2. I gave a proof for $n+1$ for simplicity. You can get $n$ by observing that $(\tau_1,\dots, \tau_n)$ lies in a $n-1$ dimensional subspace (since $\sum \tau_i = 1$).

Comment: Applogize for my ignorance. $S$ is player I's pure strategy space, so $v(S) = \{(f(s,t_1), f(s,t_2), \ldots ,f(s,t_n)): s \in S\}$. $\operatorname{conv}(S) = \{\sum_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_i s_i: s_i \in S, n \in \Bbb N, \sum_{i =1}^{n} \alpha_i = 1\}$. I can't see why $v(S)$ is an element of $\operatorname{conv}(S)$.

Comment: $v(\sigma) = \mathbb{E}_{s\sim \sigma}[u(s)]$. The following post explains why $v(\sigma) \in \mathrm{conv}(S)$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284153/mathematical-expectation-is-inside-convex-hull-of-support

Comment: Dear Sir，tons of thanks！Without your help， it would be impossible for me to understand it.